# VBA Regular Expression Mail

Tags: excel, vba

I want to split a string into 3 parts. For example i have a email adress like

```
testuser@gamil.com
```

and i want to split it into

```
testuser 
gamil
.com
```

with left, right and mid (str) i only can extract a string if is a fixed lenght. 
Has anybody some ideas to make it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3480/searching-within-strings-for-the-presence-of-substrings#t=20161115192324085467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with `left`, `right` and `mid` (str) i only can extract a string if is a fixed length.

This is not actually true, because you can also use the `len` function to get the length of the string.

```
Dim L as Integer
L = Len("testuser@gamil.com")
MsgBox L
```

You can also use the `Instr` (and `InstrRev`, reversed) function to *find* the index of a particular character or substring.

```
Dim I as Integer
I = Instr("testuser@gamil.com", "@")
```

So, for your case, a custom function without regex will return an array of three items:

```
Function SplitEmail(email$)
'Function returns an array like:
'  {"username", "domain", "tld"}

Dim Dot As Integer, At As Integer
Dot = InStrRev(email, ".")
At = InStr(email, "@")

Dim ret(1 To 3) As String

ret(1) = Left(email, At - 1)
ret(2) = Mid(email, At + 1, Dot - At - 1)
ret(3) = Mid(email, Dot + 1)

SplitEmail = ret

End Function
```

To get the username part, you could do:

```
Dim some_email$
some_email = "testuser@gamil.com"

MsgBox SplitEmail(some_email)(1)
```